# how to use repository pattern in blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I'm going to use repository Design pattern in Laravel.
I have no problem implementing repository pattern in the control section
But I have a question that I need guidance
And my question is how to use the repository on the blade?
Am I wrong?

Comment: .blade.php is templating for creating views. Data retrieval or manipulation has no place being used in a view

Comment: @apokryfos in some cases i need to use the methods of an model , but in view i want to use repository method which i cant access to them

Comment: The repositories would deal with data storage and retrieval so you should not be calling any of those methods in the view. Can you provide a practical example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @apokryfos ,yes thats right , I was a little confused about how it works and now I understand
But is there an optimal way ?
I mean, is this the right way for me to have direct access to my model methods on my blade?

Comment: In general if it's simple getters, or basic calculations you can call these methods in the view. Just as a sidenote: when you do `$model->attribute` then you are actually calling a method (since in Laravel attributes are accessed via the `__get` magic method) so if it's things as simple as that then it's probably fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no repository pattern for balde views.
Repo pattern is only for differentiating your code logic and bussiness logic.